# Efficient Calculation of an N-Dimensional Cross Product?

Tags: math, optimization, vector, cross-product

As per the title, is the best way to calculate the n-dimensional cross product just using the determinant definition and using the LU Decomposition method of doing as such or could you guys suggest a better one?

Thanks

Edit: for clarity I mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product and not the Cartesian Product

Edit: It also seems that using the Leibniz Formula might help - though I don't know how that compares to LU Decomp. at the moment.

Comment: You don't want the Leibniz formula for large N -- it gets expensive fast!  For N>4, the LU decomposition method is probably the way to go.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “cross product”? The Wikipedia article you quote states a seven-dimensional one, and then says that “In general dimension, there is no direct analogue of the binary cross product that yields specifically a vector”. Do you mean a wedge product, or something else?

Comment: @MvG yup sorry, I meant the wedge product, I think? I meant this part ". Also, using the orientation and metric structure just as for the traditional 3-dimensional cross product, one can in n dimensions take the product of n − 1 vectors to produce a vector perpendicular to all of them. But if the product is limited to non-trivial binary products with vector results, it exists only in three and seven dimensions." In specific the product of n-1 vectors assuming it exists - also how do you know if it is limited to non trivial binary products? E.g. a check?

Comment: “binary product” means you want an operation which takes two vectors as input, as opposed to the $n-1$ vectors you mentioned. “non-trivial” means that it will not simply “compute” the null vector independent from its input. The wedge product is binary as well. Do you care bout the length of the result, or only about its orthogonality? If the latter, then you're simply looking for (an element of) the [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29) of the $(n-1)\times n$ matrix formed by the input vectors. There are various ways to compute that kernel, e.g. using Lapack.

Answer (score 4):

From your comment, it seems like you are looking for an operation which takes *n* −1 vectors as input and computes a single vector as its result, which will be orthogonal to all the input vectors and perhaps have a well-defined length as well.

## With defined length

You can characterize the 3-dimensional cross product *v* =*a* ×*b* using the identity *v* ∙*w* =det(*a*,*b*,*w*). In other words, taking the cross product of the input vectors and then computing the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) with *any* other vector *w* is the same as plugging the input vectors and that other vector into a matrix and computing its [determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant).

This definition can be [generalized to arbitrary dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra). Due to the way a determinant can be computed using [Laplace expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) along the last column, the resulting coordinates of that cross product will be the values of all (*n* −1)×(*n* −1) sub-determinants you can form from the input vectors, with alternating signs. So yes, [Leibniz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) might be useful in theory, although it is hardly suitable for real-world computations. In practice, you'll soon have to figure out ways to avoid repeating computationswhile [computing these *n* determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Calculation). But wait for the last section of this answer…

## Just the direction

Most applications however can do with a weaker requirement. They don't care about the *length* of the resulting vector, but only about its *direction*. In that case, what you are asking for is the [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29) of the (*n* −1)×*n* matrix you can form by taking the input vectors as rows. Any element of that kernel will be orthogonal to the input vectors, and since computing kernels is a common task, you can build on a lot of [existing](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/linear-equations.shtml) [implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29#Computation_of_the_null_space_on_a_computer), e.g. [Lapack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapack). Details might depend on the language you are using.

## Combining these

You can even combine the two approaches above: compute one element of the kernel, and for a non-zero entry of that vector, also compute the corresponding (*n* −1)×(*n* −1) determinant which would give you that single coordinate using the first approach. You can then simply scale the vector so that the selected coordinate reaches the computed value, and all the other coordinates will match that one.